# Topcoder SRM666 Div1 WalkOverATree analysis

Tags: algorithm, tree

My question is for a specific input pattern to the below problem statement.

```
Say if input is
{0,0,0,0,2,4,3,1}
4
```

The output should be 3 right? Why are most of the output 4? 
The tree will look like

```
0->1->8,0->2->5,0->3->7,0->4->6
```

Max height is 2(so 2 steps), so backtracking has to be to root(0th Node) - which is 2 steps. So he can visit only 3 nodes? But the answer seems incorrect and it is 4. What am i missing here?

> The problem statement is below - from TopCoder SRM666 Div1

Given is a tree on n nodes. The nodes are numbered 0 through n-1. You are given the description of the tree as a int[] parent with n-1 elements. For each valid i, there is an edge between vertices (i+1) and parent[i].

A person is currently standing in node 0. In a single step, the person can move from its current node to any adjacent node. You are given an int L. The person is allowed to make at most L steps.

Return the maximum number of nodes the person can visit during the walk. Node 0 (where the walk starts) and the node where the walk ends count as visited. Each visited node is only counted once, even if it is visited multiple times.

Definition

```
Class:  WalkOverATree
Method: maxNodesVisited
Parameters: int[], int
Returns:    int
Method signature:   int maxNodesVisited(int[] parent, int L)
(be sure your method is public)

Examples 
0)  
         {0, 0} 2 Returns: 2 The tree consists of edges 1-0 and 2-0. Our person will start in node 0 and can make at most L=2 steps. In two
 steps, the best we can do is visit one of the nodes 1 and 2. 

1)  
         {0, 0} 3 Returns: 3 This is the same tree, only now we have L=3. In three steps the person can visit all three nodes: for example, by
 going from node 0 to node 1, back to node 0, and finally to node 2.
 Note that even though the person visited node 0 twice, we only count
 it once. 

2)  
         {0, 1, 2, 3} 2 Returns: 3
```

Comment: With 4 steps available, the person can go 0->1->0->2->5, for a total number of visited nodes equal to 4 (i.e. 0, 1, 2, and 5).

Comment: Ah! you are right. makes sense now. Thanks